# ZMQ socket queue

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I'm pretty new with ZMQ and I'm working with the NodeJS binding. I have an application that uses `PUSH/PULL` sockets. On one side I `PUSH` data to some nodes that through the `PULL` socket receive and process it. Sometimes I have to kill one or more nodes of my application, and it can happen that these nodes still have some data in the `PULL` socket to be processed. I don't want to lose this data, so I was wondering if there is a way to access ZMQ's `PULL` socket queue to check if there are still messages to be processed.

I actually couldn't find anything in the specs of ZMQ and the NodeJS binding, so maybe I'm getting the whole concept wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the solution I found. It's not really a solution as I'm not using the ZMQ socket to check that there are no more messages in the queue, it's just a workaround/hack that came to my mind to make the thing work. I don't have time to write the queue handling by myself, so here's how I solved the problem:

Whenever the processes receive messages to process, they store a timestamp through `new Date().getTime()`. Whenever a process needs to be killed a `kill` message is sent to it. As the process receives the message, it starts a timeout with `setInterval`. Every `x` seconds (I put 10, can be more or less) the timeout fires a function that checks if the last received message is old enough (takes a timestamp, subtract this ts with the last one saved and if the result is greater that `y`, which in my case is 100 seconds, it is old enough). If it is, it means no more messages have been received (no more messages in the queue) so it kills the process, otherwise does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you kill a process then any data in that processes buffers will be lost.

Instead of killing the process forcefully, you should always find a way to allow processes to shut-down gracefully. Here, you can send a "KILL" message to the PULL socket; the process can then read that and exit when it receives it. If you can flush the socket buffer (depends if there are other processes still sending to it), you can do that and then exit when there are no more messages to read.

Comment: Well, thanks, that's what I had in mind. My question was more "how do I check if there are still messages to process before killing the socket?".

Comment: That depends a lot on your architecture; if there are pushers sending continuously, the queue will never be guaranteed empty. If the pushers know when a session ends they can add a "kill" message that signals this.

Comment: Pushers will keep sending stuff, but whenever I start a "kill" procedure, the pushers are unbinded from the worker, thus the worker ends up receiving no more messages, but may have some still unprocessed in the queue. I needed to check the status of the queue and get the right moment to kill the process.